# Pandas - Filter across all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a square correlation matrix in pandas, and am trying to divine the most efficient way to return all values where the value (always a float -1 <= x <= 1) is above a certain threshold.

The [pandas.DataFrame.filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method  asks for a list of columns or a RegEx, but I always want to pass all columns in. Is there a best practice on this?

Comment: Can you add sample with desired output? If values out of conditions then are replaced by `NaN` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what you desired output is since you didn't provide a sample, but I'll give you my two cents on what I would do:

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))  
corr = df.corr()
corr.shape

Out[1]: (5, 5)
```

Now, let's extract the upper triangle of the correlation matrix (it's symetric), **excluding the diagonal**. For this we are going to use [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html#numpy.tril), cast this as a boolean, and get the opposite of it using the `~` operator.

```
In [2]: corr_triu = corr.where(~np.tril(np.ones(corr.shape)).astype(np.bool))
         corr_triu
Out[2]: 
    0         1         2         3         4
0 NaN  0.228763 -0.276406  0.286771 -0.050825
1 NaN       NaN -0.562459 -0.596057  0.540656
2 NaN       NaN       NaN  0.402752  0.042400
3 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.642285
4 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Now let's stack this and filter all values that are above `0.3` for example:

```
In [3]: corr_triu = corr_triu.stack()
        corr_triu[corr_triu > 0.3]
Out[3]: 
1  4    0.540656
2  3    0.402752
dtype: float64
```

If you want to make it a bit prettier:

```
In [4]: corr_triu.name = 'Pearson Correlation Coefficient'
        corr_triu.index.names = ['Col1', 'Col2']

In [5]: corr_triu[corr_triu > 0.3].to_frame()
Out[5]: 
           Pearson Correlation Coefficient
Col1 Col2                   
1    4              0.540656
2    3              0.402752
```

Comment: I upvoted because this taught me a good method for dealing with the case of a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways to go about this:

Suppose:

```
In [7]: c = np.array([-1,-2,-2,-3,-4,-6,-7,-8])

In [8]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9])

In [9]: b = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12,13,15])

In [10]: c = np.array([-1,-2,-2,-3,-4,-6,-7,-8])

In [11]: corr = np.corrcoef([a,b,c])

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(corr)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
          0         1         2
0  1.000000  0.995350 -0.980521
1  0.995350  1.000000 -0.971724
2 -0.980521 -0.971724  1.000000
```

Then you can simply:

```
In [14]: df > 0.5
Out[14]:
       0      1      2
0   True   True  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False   True

In [15]: df[df > 0.5]
Out[15]:
         0        1    2
0  1.00000  0.99535  NaN
1  0.99535  1.00000  NaN
2      NaN      NaN  1.0
```

If you want only the values, then the easiest way is to work with the underlying numpy data structures using the `values` attribute:

```
In [17]: df.values
Out[17]:
array([[ 1.        ,  0.99535001, -0.9805214 ],
       [ 0.99535001,  1.        , -0.97172394],
       [-0.9805214 , -0.97172394,  1.        ]])

In [18]: df.values[(df > 0.5).values]
Out[18]: array([ 1.        ,  0.99535001,  0.99535001,  1.        ,  1.        ])
```

Instead of `.values`, as pointed out by ayhan, you can use `stack` which automatically drops `NaN` and also keeps labels...

```
In [22]: df.index = ['a','b','c']

In [23]: df.columns=['a','b','c']

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
          a         b         c
a  1.000000  0.995350 -0.980521
b  0.995350  1.000000 -0.971724
c -0.980521 -0.971724  1.000000


In [25]: df.stack() > 0.5
Out[25]:
a  a     True
   b     True
   c    False
b  a     True
   b     True
   c    False
c  a    False
   b    False
   c     True
dtype: bool

In [26]: df.stack()[df.stack() > 0.5]
Out[26]:
a  a    1.00000
   b    0.99535
b  a    0.99535
   b    1.00000
c  c    1.00000
dtype: float64
```

You can always go back...

```
In [29]: (df.stack()[df.stack() > 0.5]).unstack()
Out[29]:
         a        b    c
a  1.00000  0.99535  NaN
b  0.99535  1.00000  NaN
c      NaN      NaN  1.0
```

Comment: In addition to `values`, `stack()` is also useful as it automatically drops NaN's but keeps labels.

Comment: Your solution definitely feels more natural than mine, but I would caution that it does maintain unnecessary items (the `('x','x')` ones that are necesarilly always 1) as well as permutations: `('a','b')` is the same as `('b','a')`. (And that's fine since we still don't know the exact OP's requirements, so I upvoted it)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is a strong way of looking at it too! I think Julien's feels a little more eloquent/Pythonic but I see use cases for this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Drop NaN for easy reading.

```py
df[df > 100].dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Answer (score 1):

For easily get a meaningful correlation result from a pandas dataframe;

For example our data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),
                columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df
```

we get the **correlation** between the values with `df.corr()`

To filter the result by **ignoring the 1.0 (which are correlation of same values)** and filter a limit by;

```
corr_result=df.corr() 
corr_result = corr_result.stack()
corr_result[(corr_result != 1.0)&((corr_result > 0.9)|(corr_result < -0.9))]
```