# Filtering pandas dataframe rows based on boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
             col_1  | col_2  | col_3 .... col_100
date
01-01-2001   True    False  False   ...   True
02-01-2001   False   True   False   ...   True
03-01-2001   True    False  True    ...   True
04-01-2001   False   False  False   ...   False
```

as a result, I'd like to get a df that contains all the rows which have at least one True in the row. In this case, the results would be

```
             col_1  | col_2  | col_3 ... col_100
date
01-01-2001   True    False  False   ...  True
02-01-2001   False   True   False   ...  True
03-01-2001   True    False  True    ...  False
```

Any clever way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using [stack()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41128456/38368)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.any(axis=1)]
```

Out of box:

```
df1 = df[df.sum(axis=1).gt(0)]
```